# Insert data to database table with non static name (FMDB)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fmdb

I have a project where dynamically creating tables in database. And I didn't know what is table are used in some moment. And want something like this:
`[db executeQuery:@"INSERT INTO %@Table (image) VALUES (?)",tableName,imageData];`
But it didn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a string and then use this string to do the query, something like that:

```
NSString* queryStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@(image) VALUES (?) ",tableName];
[db executeQuery:queryStr,imageData];
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is another function in FMDB if you want to use a format string. You will have to use `executeQueryWithFormat:` instead of `executeQuery:`.

If `tableName` is "Employees" your string would evaluate to:

```
"INSERT INTO EmployeesTable (image) values (<data>)"
```

Is that what you want (i.e. adding the string "Table" to the table name)?